# Qt::Key_F9 case gets implemented even when I push Key_F10 or Key_F11

Tags: qt, visual-c++

I ran into rather a weird scenario, where I'm using QT keys to implement some functions, but even after separating them into different cases( for F9, F10, and F11), whenever I press F10 or F11, it goes to F9 case first (implements KeyF9()) and then implements their own perspective function(KeyF10()/KeyF11()).

```
if ((e->key() & Qt::Key_F9) == Qt::Key_F9)
    KeyF9();
if ((e->key() & Qt::Key_F10) == Qt::Key_F10)
    KeyF10();
if ((e->key() & Qt::Key_F11) == Qt::Key_F11)
    KeyF11();
```

Has anyone else come across a similar situation then please help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use Qt::key's enum like masks, because it's not.

```
if(e->key()  == Qt::Key_F9)
    KeyF9();
```

will be ok.